# Using Intelligencia UrlRewriter regex .asp pages to a holding page

Tags: regex, web-config, urlrewriter

When looking over the statistics for my site, I realized that the vast majority of traffic is coming via third party links to classic ASP pages which haven't existing for a few years now.

I decided that adding a bunch of urlMappings to the web.config wasn't a great idea, so I added Intelligencia UrlRewrite and tried to add a rule, as follows:

```
  <rewriter>
    <redirect url="^/(.*).asp$" to="~/pagenotfound.aspx?page=$1" />
  </rewriter>
```

The rule works, but it picks up any url which ends with .asp = such as /pagenotfound.aspx?page=someurl.asp.

Oops :)

I'm not exactly knowledgeable about regular expressions, how can I get it to ignore ".asp" which follows the question mark character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <rewriter>
    <redirect url="^/([^?]*)\.asp(\?.*)?$" to="~/pagenotfound.aspx?page=$1" />
  </rewriter>
```

That should make it ignore any URL which ends in .asp but contains a ? before it. The [^?] means "any character that's not a ?" instead of the * which means "any character".

Edit: Added extra pattern to allow query strings *after* a .asp extension but not before them.

Comment: Dav,

Thanks for the response. While this works, it means it no longer picks up .asp pages with a query string which is sort of defeating my purpose - I need to detect any legitmate .asp url and redirect, while not capturing .asp which happens to be in a query string.

Thanksl

Comment: Heya Richard - you should be able to extend the url regex to add the potential for a query string after the .asp extension - I've edited my example above for something that I *believe* will work (not 100% sure if I nailed the syntax on it though).

Comment: I also added the backslash that should be in front of that first period (for .asp) - otherwise, it'll interpret it as a regular regex period which matches any character (instead of a literal period), which would result in it improperly matching something like /test.asp?asp

Comment: Nice answer Dav. The only limitation I see is that it doesn't pass the capture querystring as part of the rewrite. Changing the regex to ^/([^?]*)\.asp\??(.*)?$ and the result to ?page=$1&$2 would allow for that.

Comment: Unfortunately that causes other problems, Chris - the regex you suggest would then match /test.aspx (due to the optionality of the ? being independent of the optionality for the .*) which would break the core requirements for the initial problem. Instead, what you'd actually need is this: ^/([^?]*)\.asp(\?(.*))?$ and then use the result of ?page=$1&$3 - however, since Richard appears to be leaving off the .asp, and the rewrite destination is "pagenotfound.aspx", I'm guessing that the actual contents of the query string aren't all that important to him - he just wants all .asp urls to rewrite.

Comment: Dav/Chris,

Thanks for the answers. The updated regex works great :) While originally my main goal was simply to record and redirect these invalid urls, pulling out the query string wasn't a bad idea either :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite url="^~/browse/([^/.]+)\.aspx?$"
 to="~/browse-prints.aspx?dispCat=$1"/>

<rewrite url="^~/browse/([^/.]+)\.aspx(\?.*)?$"
 to="~/browse-prints.aspx$2&amp;dispCat=$1"/>
```